# Redefine datatemplate style

Tags: wpf, styles, datatemplate

Suppose I define a style for a TextBlock on application level, and I also define a DataTemplate for a 'DataClass' on application level that uses some TextBlocks. Now, in some subpart of the application I want to redefine how a TextBlock looks, I could just redefine the Style for TextBlock.

The problem here is: if the DataTemplate is applied in this subpart of the application, all TextBlocks inside will still use the application-level TextBlock style (instead of my redefined version). Does anyone know how to redefine the style of a DataTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

Styles in `<Application.Resources>` apply to the entire application, and do not always follow default style lookup rules.

Typically if you don't want that behavior, put the style in `<Window.Resources>` instead, so they will only apply to objects inside your window, and will use the normal style lookup rules.

By default, styles do not get applied across control/template boundaries, *except* for styles for objects that inherit from `Control`, which are most default WPF controls such as `Label` or `TextBox`.

So you can set the style of any `Control` object in an object's `.Resources` to have it apply to all child objects:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

But `TextBlock` inherits from `FrameworkElement` and not `Control`, so styles for a `TextBlock` won't be applied across template boundaries.

If you do want to keep your style in `Application.Resources`, then you'll have to overwrite the properties from that style further down the visual tree right before you create the `TextBlock`, such as

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyDataTypeView"... >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <TextBlock Text="Test" />
</UserControl>
```

However this style won't get applied to objects inside another control in the `UserControl`, such as the text for `ComboBoxItems` inside a `ComboBox`

A `TextBlock` used inside a child control will apply a `TextBlock` style from `Application.Resources`, but not from `<UserControl.Resources>` because TextBlock styles defined in `Application.Resources` will cross control/template boundaries, while a TextBlock style defined in any other `X.Resources` will not.

In these specific situations, you may need to track down what `x:Static` brush key is used for setting the `TextBlock.Text` color and overwrite that in your `ComboBox.Resources`, such as

(I may have the wrong [SystemColors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference.aspx) key here)

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

Comment: ok thanks, some interesting info on the boundaries. But like you say Styles defined in a Control don't cross DataTemplate boundaries, this is actually what I need. I would like to redefine a property in the datatemplate (eg. BackGroundColor) for all children in a certain Control. From what you write, I understand that this may not be possible?

Comment: @user1896048 Styles defined in a Control don't get inherited across control/template boundaries *except* if the style is for an object that inherits from `Control`, which most Controls do. For example, a `Label` inherits from `Control` so styles would get inherited in child Labels, however `TextBlock` does not so styles for it won't get inherited. You can also make a generic style, such as `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">` and set the `Background` property there to have it apply to all objects that inherit from `Control`, or you can overwrite a `SystemColor` such as my last code example.

Comment: actually, this suprises me. I thought Styles were resolved through 'scope' and not inheritance (the passing from parent to children kind of inheritance), since they are Resources ... Do you know of any official source discussing how element-type Styles are resolved?

Comment: @user1896048 You're right, I should have used the term `applied` instead of `inherited`. Styles aren't inherited, but are instead looked up from the application's resources and applied when needed. I don't have any links bookmarked about the exact lookup sequence, however the MSDN page on Dependency Property Precedence has section on [how the Style property is resolved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#style_property).